# How peer carries out his responsibilities

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Just recently, I have edited a question and got a message saying that once your peer will approve it, it will be posted.But I would like to know who is the peer here and how this working? Just any body can become a peer and do the needful?

Comment: I believe this differs on different Stack Exchange sites but on Stack Overflow these peers that can approve your edit are anyone with over 2000 Rep.

Comment: Forum?   ***FORUM?***

Comment: @Won't, I did not get you.sorry

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, I have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

> who is the peer here

Other users of the site with enough reputation to have edit approval privileges are your peers.

> how this working

When one such user has enough reputation they have access to a review queue where they can see edit suggestions (such as yours) and go through them - approving or rejecting them.

They can also see that a question/answer has a suggested edit when on the page and act on them.

> Just any body can become a peer and do the needful

Yes. All you need is enough reputation.

For more details see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Comment: Actually, I can approve edits even if I don't have it in review queue (comes with 5000 rep). But I would be limited only to the edits that I will see, if I step into the question.

Comment: @om-nom-nom -  Thanks for the comment. Answer updated.